# How can I get tracking data (transparently) from Android, like the data from sensors that apps routinely collect?

Tags: data-monitoring, sensors

I want to make a data science workshop. I know that some apps in smartphones in general have the ability to get tracking data, for ad, tracking and surveillance purposes.

I want to make people more conscious of this, by letting the user get this data and work with it him/herself.

Are there any more direct ways for accessing data of sensors in a given android phone (in a transparent, non-invasive way), export it to a file in the phone so that it is possible to be read by a script for data science purposes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apps don't tell you what data they collect. The easiest way to demonstrate tracking would be to display the network data using a proxy (e.g. mitmproxy) and highlight the user data stored on the phone. But as such data is usually transmitted via HTTPS you would need a modified app to allow the installed proxy user certificate or a roote device which allows to install user certificates as system certificates.

Comment: I don't know if I specified incorrectly, but I don't want to monitor apps specifically, but get sensor data in the same fashion as some apps to show what *can* be tracked, not *what* is tracked.

Comment: I think you are mixing up user location tracking with app/ad tracking. The first bases on sensor data, the latter on user interactions and user data present on the device.

Comment: For this workshow I would like to collect general sensor data (location, compass, accelerometer, etc) and put it in a CSV basically.

Comment: It sounds to me that the intention is the opposite of what is stated. Nevertheless the programming language you are using should those functions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.